# Display javascript graph NOT in web browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a program that runs in Terminal and I'd like to have a graph window open like in JPanel.  I don't care if it's rendered by chrome and then the panel pops up, I'd just like to know if this is possible?  Node.js says it uses JS not in a browser, but the graphing modules like Plotly do use the browser.

Comment: Make your program generate an HTML file and open the HTML file in a browser.

Comment: So this would result in a separate window that isn't part of a web browser with the graph in it?

Comment: That would depend entirely on how you launch the browser.

Comment: How do I launch a separate window with the graph in it, not within a browser?

Comment: That depends on what operating system it is and/or what browser.

Comment: It needs to work in both OSX Yosemite and Linux Ubuntu.  Push comes to shove it'd be Linux Ubuntu.  And Chrome I guess?

Comment: Okay, I suggest you research launching browser instances in OS X and Ubuntu. The methods will differ depending on the OS and whether you want to launch the default browser or a specific browser (in the latter case you may have more options as to how it's launched). The topic is too broad to cover in a Stack Overflow answer, but there's lots of information out there; once you've written some code you can come back here with more specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 1):

If you definitely need a separate window that is not part of a browser session, you'll probably have no choice but to use a more verbose implementation.

A straightforward approach would be to use https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/ which will allow you to open a native window to render a webpage.

Alternatively, you could go with http://phantomjs.org/ which would allow you to render the graph offscreen, then render it to an image and have that image opened by the OS.

Comment: How is nw.js used to just open a native window with the graph in it? And could a better charting library be used like d3?

Comment: Check out the "Quick Start" on their site. It explains it well. You can use any charting library you like.